# How to install dylib files on mac?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, dylib

I am trying to write a cross-platform program. This program uses libavcodec from ffmpeg to decode audio files. I downloaded the shared build from [Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). Then I copied the **.dylib** files into `/usr/local/lib`. However the linker repeatedly says: library not found for `-lavcodec`. I am sure I added the option `-L/usr/local/lib`.

What is the proper way to install these dylib files?

Comment: If you are building cross-platform, the linker is not supposed to lookup your local libs. Neither /usr/local/lib nor /usr/lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. The provided dylib files have version number appended. You have to place them elsewhere, and then create a symbolic link to them without the version number.